# NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import vk_api, random
from plugins import system, functions
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType, VkBotLongPoll

vk, longpoll = system.session()

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            event.message.get('text').split()
        if functions.check_chat(event.message.get('peer_id')) >= 1:
                print('Ок')

            else:
                if message[0] == '/start':
                    owner_id = vk.messages.getConversationsById(peer_ids=event.obj.peer_id, group_id=193736173)['items'][0]['chat_settings'][0]['owner_id']
                    text = functions.reg_chat(event.obj.peer_id, [owner_id])
                    vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id, message=f'{text}', random_id=random.randint(-1000000, 1000000))
```

> Ошибка:NameError: name 'message' is not defined в 20 строке как исправить?

Comment: Что такое `message`?

Comment: Я задал вопрос,зачем ты спрашиваешь у меня?,разве я не должен получить норм ответ?,а не вопрос

Comment: хорошо, вот ответ: определите переменную `message`

Comment: ну у тебя код неполный → неясно что откуда берется ;)

Comment: я двоешник , но строк только 18 насчитал в выложеном коде

Comment: ну видимо Ты забыл где-то указать `message = event.message.get('text').split()`, скорее всего исходят из логики

Comment: Ну когда я исправил одну строку на эту (message = event.message.get('text').split()) то появилась другая ошибка
Ошибка на 21 строке owner_id = vk.messages.getConversationsById(peer_ids=event.obj.peer_id, group_id=193736173)['items'][0]['chat_settings'][0]['owner_id']

Comment: @Артём нет, ты не должен получить норм ответ. Тут тебе никто ничем не обязан, и если хочешь помощи, то веди себя прилично.

Comment: Я просто 2 день не могу найти ответ на свой вопрос,мне 1 раз даже сказали на каком то форуме ответили точнее попробуй решить проблема,а для чего форум где можно спросить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
event.message.get('text').split()
```

вы получаете значение, потом разделяет с помощью `split` и никуда не сохраняете.

поменяйте её на эту строку это:

```
message = event.message.get('text').split()
```

Comment: Уже поменял,и у меня появилась другая ошибка я не могу проверить peer_id с помощью это го print(event.obj.peer_id) выдаёт не ошибку а просто None в командной строке пишет

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что все достаточно просто.

Как я понял, ошибка идет здесь:

> if message[0] == '/start':

Проблема в том, что вы обращаетесь к нулевому значению массива, который не закреплен за переменной. Потому просто стоит объявить переменную и присвоить ей значение необходимо массива.